# C# SqlCommand returns 0

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssms

I've created a SQL query that I execute with the following command, and it returns the correct number of entries but these contains all 0:

[image]

If I run the same SQL command in my Management Studio, it works correctly.

I also tried it with a Linq statement and it works also correctly:

[image]

I hope you guys can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I would *start* by using parameterized SQL instead of including `filter` directly into the query string. That may or may not be all that's required - it's hard to tell with relatively little schema or type information.

Comment: Please don't use images, post code instead.

Comment: Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you show an expanded view of the data returned in the straight sql query, count=0 there must be something in it or it wouldnt be returned..

Comment: The images is not only hard to read, but also imgur is blocked from my workplace, so I can't even see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be projecting into a `List<T>` - the `ToList()` does that. Basically, simplify:

```
var data = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Tuple<DateTime, string, string>>(...).ToList();
```

It *might* also work with value-tuples:

```
var data = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<(DateTime, string, string)>(...).ToList();
```

which would also allow you to conceptually name them:

```
var data = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<(DateTime Datum, string Text, string Bemerkung)>
       (...).ToList();
```

Note: concatenating `filter` is almost certainly a SQL injection vulnerability; if looks like you should be using a SQL parameter there instead.

---

@Evk notes that EF *might not* support column-wise binding of tuples. If that is the case, then your best bet would be to create a POCO that matches the column definitions:

```
class Foo // rename me to something meaningful
{
    // note: there may be custom attributes you can use
    // to make these names less ugly, i.e.
    // [Column("TEXT")] on a property called Text
    public DateTime RMA_DATUM {get;set;}
    public string TEXT {get;set;}
    public string BEMERKUNG {get;set;}
}
```

and use `SqlQuery<Foo>`.

Comment: I doubt this will work. `Tuple` doesn't have default constructor. ValueTuple does, but anyway it has properties with names like `Item1` etc, while columns returned by OP select statement have different names.

Comment: @Evk I'm not 100% sure of the capabilities of EF here, but certainly **some** ORMs/micro-ORMs detect tuples/value-tuples, and implement column-wise member binding. If EF *doesn't* do this, then indeed: it would be problematic

Comment: Well, it doesn't.